# Two representations one-dimensional are equivalent if only if they are equal

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory

Let $\phi , \psi : G \to \mathbb{C}^{*} $ be one-dimensional representations. Show that $\phi$ is equivalent to $\psi$ if and only if $\phi = \psi.$

Well, if $\phi \sim \psi$ (equivalent), then there exist a vector space isomorphism $T : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ where ${\psi}_{g} = T{\phi}_{g}T^{-1}$, for all $g \in G$. Also, since $\phi$ and $\psi$ have dimension 1 (which is the size of the vector space $\mathbb{C}$) then such representations are irreducible, that is, $\lbrace 0 \rbrace$ and $V$ are the only G-invariant subspaces under $V$.

I want to show that $\phi = \psi$, that is, that $\phi_{g}(a) = \psi_{g}(b)$ for all $g \in G$. I thought of taking $a = T^{-1}(b)$ and using the equality $\phi_{g}(a) = \phi_{g}T^{-1}(b)$ but did not succeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $T$ is one dimensional and one dimensional matrices (i.e. complex numbers) commute

Comment: In this approach will I not even need to go into the definition of irreducibility?

Comment: Every 1 dimensional representation is irreducible...

Comment: Since $\phi$, $\psi$ and $T$ are one-dimensional, then applied to any element of $\mathbb{C}$ are scalar and therefore commutate. That is:
$ (\Rightarrow ) \phi \sim \psi \Rightarrow \phi_{g} = T^{-1}\psi_{g}T \Rightarrow T\phi_{g} = \psi_{g}T \Rightarrow T\phi_{g} = T\psi_{g} (comute) \Rightarrow \phi_{g} = \psi_{g}.\\
(\Leftarrow ) \phi_{g} = \psi_{g} \Rightarrow T\phi_{g} = T\psi_{g} \Rightarrow T\phi_{g} = \psi_{g}T (comute) \Rightarrow \phi_{g} = T^{-1}\psi_{g}T.  
$
This is correct?